# Basic question on the de Rham theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, homological-algebra, differential-topology, cohomology, smooth-manifolds

There is a modern nice proof of the de Rham theorem based on sheaf theory.
The de Rham theorem says that for a smooth manifold $M$ there is a canonical isomorphism
$$H^i_{dR}(M,\mathbb{R})\simeq H^i_{sing}(M,\mathbb{R}).$$
The proof uses the resolution of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$ by the complex of sheaves of differential forms (Poincaré lemma) and the fact that the sheaves of differential forms are acyclic.

However there is a more geometric construction of an isomorphism when one considers the map from the complex of smooth differential forms to the complex of piecewise smooth singular cochains given by
$$\omega\mapsto [\sigma\mapsto \int_\sigma \omega],$$
where $\sigma$ is a singular chain. It is claimed that this map induces an isomorphism in cohomology.

**I do not see that the two isomorphisms between de Rham and singular cohomology are the same. (In fact I do not even see, but believe, that the second one is indeed an isomorphism).** For example why one isomorphism cannot be a constant times the other one?

**Remark.** In the first isomorphism the notion of integration of a differential form was not used at all.

**Another question is why both isomorphisms are isomorphisms of algebras.**

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: The first part of the question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3069883/317327

Comment: The "first isomorphism" does not exist.

Comment: @abx Can you say more?

Comment: Could you please give a reference to this new nice proof of the de Rham theorem?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov: See "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris, p. 44.

Comment: Bumped (by trivial edits) in an attempt to lure @abx into answering Will Sawin’s question 

Comment: @Francois Ziegler: Sorry I missed the question when it arose. I just meant that what the OP calls the "first isomorphism" is between $H^{i}_{dR}(M,\mathbb{R})$ and the sheaf cohomology. If you want an isomorphism with $H^{i}_{sing}(M,\mathbb{R}),$ you have to use also the cochain resolution, and that's the "second isomorphism".

Answer (score 3):

This is very nicely explained in [Dustin Clausen's notes](https://sites.google.com/view/algebraicderham/home) on de Rham cohomology, specifically in lectures 1 and 3.

The question of why the map is "the usual one" is adressed in Remark 13 of Lecture 3, and it is also made clear that all maps involved are algebra maps.